# Loop invariance insertion sort algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting, correctness-proof, python

I have the following pseudo code for a insertion sort algorithm

```
INSERTION-SORT

1 for j = 2 to A.length
2    key = A[j]
3    // Insert A[j] into the sorted sequence A[1..j-1]
4    i = j -1 
5    while i > 0 and A[i] > key
6        A[i+1] = A[i]
7         i = i -1
8    A[i+1] = key
```

I am trying to convert it into executable code written in Python

```
def main():
    A = [5,2,4,6,1,3]
    for j in range(1,len(A)):
        key = A[j]
        i = j - 1
        while i >= 0 and A[i] > key:
            A[i + 1] = A[i]
            i = i - 1
        A[i + 1] = key
        print A[0:j+1]
    return A
 
main()
```

is this a correct translation? I'm not sure if I messed something up with the indexes because it seems as though I'm not getting the end index with range. Furthermore I'm going to be testing correctness with initialization, maintenance and termination.

I added the line `print A[0:j]` to show initialization and maintenance but I'm not sure if it should be `print A[0:j-1]`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. `I'm not sure if I messed something up …` hard to follow not given any specification. `it seems as though I'm not getting the end index with range` there are fine manuals about [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) and [slices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations). (I seem to remember loop invariant. While programming questions are off-topic here, your question *may* be about the semantics of Python *range*s & *slicing*, which I'd consider border-line.)

Answer (score 1):

Python arrays have [0-based indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), like in C, and unlike Fortran, which uses [1-based indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type#Index_origin). You can check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array)#Array_dimensions) for information about other languages.

A python array $A$ of length $n$ consists of the elements $A[0],\ldots,A[n-1]$. The python function `range(n)` goes over the indices $0,\ldots,n-1$, and your `range(1,n)` goes over the indices $1,\ldots,n-1$.

In insertion sort, we go over all prefixes of the array inductively, and make sure that they are sorted. If $A[0],\ldots,A[j-1]$ is already sorted, in order to make $A[0],\ldots,A[j]$ sorted, we just need to more the current $A[j]$ into its proper location. Since $A[0]$ is automatically sorted, we only need to go over $j=1,j=2,\ldots,j=n-1$, at which point the entire array $A[0],\ldots,A[n-1]$ is sorted. This is why the loop goes over `range(1,n)`.

Is your implementation correct? Practically speaking, the best way to find out is to test it on many inputs. While such a test cannot verify that the algorithm is correct, and could miss some corner cases, it is also likely to catch off-by-one errors, especially in a language like python with [bounds checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking). Since insertion sort is such a simple algorithm, you are likely to catch any implementation errors by sorting small random arrays.

Comment: how can i show using code that the loop invariant is correct with like a print statement? As it seems that A[1..j-1] isnt true for the python version

Comment: You can add code that checks that the first $j$ elements are sorted after iteration $j$.

Comment: do you have an example of where to place it in the python code? I tried for 2 hours now and i just cant wrap my head around it

Comment: Whenever the loop invariance should hold, you can add code that checks that it holds.

Comment: thats what i did i think, after every j iteration ends it prints print A[0:j]

Comment: You don't need to print anything in order to check the loop invariant.

Comment: The loop invariant should hold before entering the loop, and at the end of each iteration.

Comment: ah okay sorry to ask alot but what is the loop invariant in the python version then? In the pseudo code it is A[1..j-1], but due to the index differences is it just A[0..j] in python?

Comment: You'll have to figure this one out.